# logging recursive dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, logging

Having an odd time getting this to work;

I have a dictionary that contains the information for several machines. Based on a parameter, the machine is selected.

I would like to write the selected information to the log. But my attempts at recursion don't seem to get me where I need to go. I get the key but the value fails.

This is the dictionary

```
CSTU_CFG =  {'A07': {             
        'password': 'CastAIP',                          # default cast password( too lazy to use LDAP)
        'host':'JSIPVWCASTD01',
        'port':'2280',                                  # Ports are assumed to be 2280 but can be any 
        'location': 'C:Users/WDI/Documents/CSTU/DMPRST',  # use os.path to convert
        'gzips': 'GZIPS',                               # location for zip files ( Backup )
        'schematype':{'local', 'central', 'mngt'},
        'logintv': 30,
        'version': '0.9'
        },
         'A01': {
        'machine': 'A01',
        'password': 'CastAIP',                          # default cast password( too lazy to use LDAP)
        'host':'JSIPVWCASTD01',
        'port':'2280',                                  # Ports are assumed to be 2280 but can be any 
        'location': 'C:Users/WDI/Documents/CSTU/DMPRST',  # use os.path to convert
        'gzips': 'GZIPS',                               # location for zip files ( Backup )
        'schematype':{'local', 'central', 'mngt'},
        'logintv': 30,
        'version': '0.9'
        },
        'A02': {
        'machine': 'A02',
        'password': 'CastAIP',                          # default cast password( too lazy to use LDAP)
        'host':'JSIPVWCASTD01',
        'port':'2280',                                  # Ports are assumed to be 2280 but can be any 
        'location': 'C:Users/WDI/Documents/CSTU/DMPRST',  # use os.path to convert
        'gzips': 'GZIPS',                               # location for zip files ( Backup )
        'schematype':{'local', 'central', 'mngt'},
        'logintv': 30,
        'version': '0.9'
        }
    }

logname = 'CSTU_'+timestr+'_'+ schemaname + '.CLOG'        
logging.basicConfig(filename=logname,filemode='a',format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("Starting CSTU_DUMP")

# print the CSTU_CFG file into the log

for key,value in CSTU_CFG:
   logging.debug(key + " => " + value)
```

I'm obviously not getting the point on the logging. I've tried a few of the suggested fixes and I either get nothing, or various errors. I Can  hard code it obviously but thats not the intent. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over dictionary to get key and that key's value:

```
for k, v in CSTU_CFG.iteritems():
     logging.debug(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate dictionary items you need to access the items first, not iterate the dictionary directly.

You need to change your code (`for key,value in CSTU_CFG`) as follows.

For Python 2.x:

```
for key, value in CSTU_CFG.iteritems():
    logging.debug(key + " => " + str(value))
```

For Python 3.x:

```
for key, value in CSTU_CFG.items():
    logging.debug(key + " => " + str(value))
```

By the way, you said you're getting errors. It may help to include the exact error trace next time in your question.

Comment: Thank you - that made sense and worked perfectly. The logging required a string so I needed to recast key and value as a string but it worked nicely. Thank you ! ( and I will include the various errors next time. Thank you again )

Comment: Looking for how, now. Thanks